# How to hide ngx-toaster programmatically?

Tags: angular, ngx-toastr

I use ngx-toaster with `disableTimeOut` true. So it won't hide automatically. But now I won't to hide it programmatically, when user leaving the page(inside the ngOnDestroy method). How can I do it?

```
this.toastr.error(message, status, {disableTimeOut: true});
```

Comment: So you want to hide toaster inside ngOnDestroy?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just have to call the .clear() method and pass the toastId If needed

```
 this.toastr.clear(this.toastRef.toastId);
```

[STACKBLITZ DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-toastr-custom-cyypmk?file=app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Thank you, this works. But small mistake, ToastId should be toastId.

Answer (score 3):

Use clear()

```
this.toastr.clear()
```